# React update component from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, components

i have a header component and posts container component in my web app. They are both separate and children of App component. The posts container is self contained and does all the firebase requests. I need in the header buttons like NEW, which will show only new posts.

The problem is that i dont have any access to the postContainer from the header. I am using redux, so i can update state in redux and get that information, but i need to update the postsContainer, so that it actualy uses the information from redux.

I have no idea how to do that. I cant just reload whole page, because redux state will get reset, so i just need to somehow force update of that whole postsContainer component. GetPosts functions is in componentDidUpdate, so i need to either trigger componentDidUpdate or the function getPosts specificaly.

I cant create new parent component now, it would be easier to just make these buttons part of the PostsContainer component.

**So basicaly i just need to trigger function or ComponentDidUpdate in component A from component B after button is pressed in component B. If its possible in any way.**

As mentioned i am using Redux and ReactRouter.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please, post https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem instead of trying to describe it with words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React update component state from another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253053/react-update-component-state-from-another-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. After you press a button in component B, trigger an update on Redux store, and set some flag or change a property. Connect component A to redux and listen to the changes on the store. Using `mapStateToProps` map states from redux store to props in component A.

After that, using `ComponentWillReceiveProps` compare `this.props.changedProp` and `nextProps.changedProp` and when the change occurs that is the point where you do your thing.