# How to update a component based on changes in another component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, styles

There are two components which don't have parent-child or sibling relationship between them.

One of them build the Toolbar and another one contains a color picker. The idea is to change the color of the Toolbar based on the value set in the color picker.

Here is my code so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { ChromePicker } from 'react-color';

export default class Banner extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      displayColorPicker: false,
      background: '#fff',
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ displayColorPicker: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ displayColorPicker: false });
  };

  handleChange = color => {
    this.setState({ background: color.hex });
  };

  handleChangeComplete = color => {
    this.setState({ background: color.hex });
  };

  render() {
    const popover = {
      position: 'absolute',
      zIndex: '2',
    };
    const cover = {
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '0px',
      right: '0px',
      bottom: '0px',
      left: '0px',
    };
    return (
      <div className="banner-container settings-banner">
        <table className="settings-banner-container">
          <tbody>
            <tr className="setttings-container-tr">
              <div
                className="xx"
                style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.background }}>
                <div className="title-cell-value settings-banner-title">
                  Brand color
                </div>
                <div>
                  <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Pick Color</Button>
                  {this.state.displayColorPicker ? (
                    <div style={popover}>
                      <div
                        style={cover}
                        onClick={this.handleClose}
                        onKeyDown={this.handleClick}
                        role="button"
                        tabIndex="0"
                        aria-label="Save"
                      />
                      <ChromePicker
                        color={this.state.background}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeComplete}
                      />
                    </div>
                  ) : null}
                </div>
              </div>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the above file, the ChromePicker is used to choose a color and save its value in `this.state.background`. I'm using that value to update the color of div with class `xx`. This works good, the div's color is updated directly.

However, I don't know how to "export" that color value outside and use it in another component.

In this case it would be the Toolbar, I want to send the value from `this.state.background` to the `style = {{ .. }}`

Is there a way to do it?

```
import React from 'react';
import Logo from '../Logo/Logo';

export default class Toolbar extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="corporate-toolbar" style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
        <Logo corporate />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253053/react-update-component-state-from-another-component

Comment: @MostafaRahmati it says that the components should be children of the same component, which is not the case in this case. I was thinking if it's possible with Redux. to save that value in Redux and the other component to get it from there

Comment: Yes i assume redux will work or useContext ( https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext )

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways to do it

You can use **`context`***(best solution)*, **`redux`***(if you app is really big)* or just move the property to the `common parent` and pass it to components *(it's the worst way, not recommended)*

Documentation for context - `https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html`

Documentation for redux - `https://react-redux.js.org`

A simple example of using context `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-usecontext`

Comment: Possibly also [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up), which IMO is the easiert for small implemenations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example using context:

```js
//in file ColorContext.js (should export but breaks snippet)
const ColorContext = React.createContext();
const ColorProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState('#fff');
  return (
    <ColorContext.Provider value={{ color, setColor }}>
      {children}
    </ColorContext.Provider>
  );
};
//in file Banner.js
class Banner extends React.PureComponent {
  handleChange = (color) => {
    this.context.setColor(color);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: this.context.color }}>
        <select
          value={this.context.color}
          onChange={(e) =>
            this.handleChange(e.target.value)
          }
        >
          <option value="#fff">fff</option>
          <option value="#f00">f00</option>
          <option value="#f0f">f0f</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
//ColorContext is imported from ColorContext.js
Banner.contextType = ColorContext;
//in file Toolbar.js
class Toolbar extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1 style={{ backgroundColor: this.context.color }}>
        Toolbar
      </h1>
    );
  }
}
//ColorContext is imported from ColorContext.js
Toolbar.contextType = ColorContext;

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Banner />
    <Toolbar />
  </div>
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <ColorProvider>
    <App />
  </ColorProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: could you join me in a chat room? I think your solution is good but I still cannot implement it

Comment: @LeoMessi Can you create a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cancel-previous-requests-7k9t8?file=/src/index.js) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: it's too complicated to create a sandbox because there are many dependencies. here is the Banner file: https://pastebin.com/YCSBgzsm, here is the Toolbar: https://pastebin.com/qaaCfXjz. I added your code into these files. At this moment I get an error in Toolbar at line 34: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined`

Comment: I don't know how to "glue" the context between those files

Comment: @LeoMessi You should import the context in Toolbar, put context code in a separate file.

Comment: @LeoMessi Updated question, you have to put the context in it's own file and import it from your components. In order for it to work you have to export ColorContext and ColorProvider